# Activity Indicator Will Not Stop or Hide

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a custom activity indicator (http://swiftonic.com/customized-activity-indicator-in-swift-3/) for my IOS webview application.  It is working but the issue I am having is that the indicator does not hide or disappear when the page is loading.  The animation just continues. Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myWebView: WKWebView!
//@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // In order to   Show activityIndicatorView
    ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

    // In order to hide activityIndicatorView
    ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

    let url = URL(string: "https://oasis.geneseo.edu")!
    myWebView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
    myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

}
```

According to the directions `ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)` should show the indicator and `ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)`. Here is the code from the seperate file that I store the `UIActivityIndicatorView` in.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class ViewControllerUtils {

    var container: UIView = UIView()
    var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    /*
     Show customized activity indicator,
     actually add activity indicator to passing view

     @param uiView - add activity indicator to this view
     */
    func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
        container.frame = uiView.frame
        container.center = uiView.center
        container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  80, height: 80)
        loadingView.center = uiView.center
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  50, height: 50);
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
        loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        container.addSubview(loadingView)
        uiView.addSubview(container)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
    /*
     Hide activity indicator
     Actually remove activity indicator from its super view

     @param uiView - remove activity indicator from this view
     */
    func hideActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        container.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    /*
     Define UIColor from hex value

     @param rgbValue - hex color value
     @param alpha - transparency level
     */
    func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32, alpha:Double=1.0)->UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0
        return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:CGFloat(alpha))
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you store `UIActivityIndicatorView` object? show `ViewControllerUtils` 's code too.\

Comment: can I see `show` and `hide`  body

Comment: I stored `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a separate file.  I updated my question with the `ViewControllerUtils` code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are creating 2 different `ViewControllerUtils` objects. You are showing the first one, and hiding the second one.

You can solve it as follows:

```
let indicator = ViewControllerUtils()
indicator.showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
indicator.hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  When I do that the indicator does not show at all.

Comment: That illustrates that my answer is correct. The indicator stops and hides. You are running into a new issue now: You show the indicator and hide it immediately in the next line of code. There is no time interval between showing and hiding, so it looks like it hides immediately. You will need to hide the indicator later, after the webview has loaded You can use one of the webview delegate methods for this.